# query from database where aliases result is same with user input

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, alias

I would like to display the channel that user want to search from php.In database (postgres), there is not "channel" column database, but I have "callid" database that has a format : CA1235, "CA" here means call. For the option Im using a different database.  this is the code

```
$VEChan=isset($_POST['vschannel'])?$_POST['vschannel']:'';
$queva=pg_query("SELECT callid, 
                 CASE WHEN callid like '%CA%' THEN 'call' END as channel
                 from call where channel like '%$VEChan%'
```

and it's error. I know that Column "channel" is never exist in database since I generate it in query for naming only.  But how if I would like to display those aliases name that is same with user's choice? There will be additional channels after call. EM12345 for email. CH12345 for chat and SO12345 for social media. with each has its own id ; emailid,chatid,socid need to be filtered.

Comment: You can't refer to alias in `WHERE` clause. Also please don't dump your code like that next time, just the query that really is causing the error.

Comment: @Jakub, Thanks for the advice. Any suggestion how to trick this?

Comment: Let me repeat that. You can't refer to the alias in `WHERE` clause (which doesn't even make much sense as all the results of channel are either 'call' or NULL). Just filter on callid column.

Comment: @Jakub. There will be additional channels after call. EM12345 for email. CH12345 for chat and SO12345 for social media. with each has its own id ; emailid,chatid,socid.

Comment: Combining multiple information in a single column is bad database design. You should put the channel into its own column.

Comment: @a_horse. The condition here I must not change the design. But I'll try to talk to the maker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to refer to an alias (except for repeating the expression) is to use a derived table:

```
select *
from (
    SELECT callid, 
           CASE 
              WHEN callid like '%CA%' THEN 'call' 
           END as channel
   from call 
) t
where channel like '%$VEChan%';
```

Comment: is there anyway I can implement it to the current code? so that I can filter which channel must be displayed from the its id, following the user's choice

Comment: @Elbert: sorry I have no idea what you are talking about. Just put the above query (with more `when` clauses of course) into your code instead of the (non-working) query you already have.